# Firebase notifications don't work after migrating to organization Apple Developer Program

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, app-store-connect, apple-developer

Today, my personal account was upgraded to organization.
Since then Firebase notifications stopped working.
When I send a notification, it shows that it was sent, but it never arrives on the device.
The breakpoints are never hit in `didReceiveRemoteNotification` or in `userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification`
 I get no error.
What could be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

I had to generate a new Key in Developer.apple.com and upload it in Firebase Messaging console